# Convergence of a complete elliptic integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions

How to prove that the following integral
assuming $k^2 < 1$ $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{d x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1-k^2 x^2}}$$ is convergent?

```
Assuming[k^2 < 1, 
 Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - k^2*x^2)], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

> ```
> EllipticK[k^2]
> ```

```
FunctionRange[{EllipticK[k^2], 0 <= k^2 < 1}, k, y, Reals]
```

> y >= Pi/2

It can also be expressed as how to prove convergence of the following elliptic integral?

```
EllipticK[k^2], (k^2<1)
```

Comment: `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - k^2*x^2)], {x, 0, 1}]`

Comment: `FunctionDomain[EllipticK[k^2], k]`

Comment: It is convergent because there is only one singularity on the path, at the endpoint `x=1`, and it is easuly seen to be integrable by series expansion: `In[188]:= Series[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2) (1 - k^2 x^2)], {x, 1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> -1 < k < 1]

Out[188]= SeriesData[x, 1, {
 2^Rational[-1, 2] (1 - k^2)^Rational[-1, 2] (1 - x)^Rational[-1, 2], 
  Rational[-1, 4]
    2^Rational[-1, 2] (
    1 - k^2)^Rational[-1, 2] (-1 + k^2)^(-1) (-1 + 5 k^2) (
    1 - x)^Rational[-1, 2]}, 0, 2, 1]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In fact the original question asks for demonstrating that the following integral is finite, what *Matematica* can do simply

```
FullSimplify[ Integrate[1/(Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - k^2 x^2]), {x, 0, 1}]  
              < Infinity,
             -1 < k < 1 ]
```

> True

A mathematical proof is comparably easy. We can see that for $\; -1< k<1$ and $\;0\leq x <1$ we have $\frac{1}{ \sqrt{1-k^2 x^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}}\;$ and so $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{1-k^2 x^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
and since the both sides of this inequality are nonnegative, integration is a generalization of summation we get $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{1-k^2 x^2}}  \leq \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2}\sqrt{1-x^2}} =\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1-k^2}}$$
recalling that   $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Q.E.D.

A counterpart of a crucial step in the proof can be demonstrated simply as well

```
Simplify[ 1/(Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - k^2 x^2]) 
          <= 1/(Sqrt[1 - x^2] Sqrt[1 - k^2]), 
                      -1 < k < 1 && 0 <= x < 1]
```

> True

We've got a better upper bound for the complete elliptic integral of the first kind namely $\frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{1-k^2}}$. Analogously we can find lower bound of the form $\frac{\pi \arcsin(k)}{2 k}$ and in a slightly different way another lower bound $\frac{\log(\frac{1-k}{1+k})}{2 k}$.
The first one works for $x$ close to $0$ and the other one for $x$ close to $1$.

We show all the graphs of appropriate functions on the following plot

```
Plot[{ EllipticK[k^2], Pi/(2 Sqrt[1 - k^2]), Pi/2 (ArcSin[k]/k), 
      Log[(1 + k)/(1 - k)]/(2 k)}, {k, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Thick, Dashed, Dashed, Dashed}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions", PlotRange -> {0, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - k^2*x^2)], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[EllipticK[k^2],  Re[k^2] <= 1 || k^2 ∉ Reals]`

```
FunctionDomain[EllipticK[k^2], k]
```

> `-1 < k < 1`

The definition domain just indicated that the `EllipticK[k^2]` converge only in `-1 < k < 1` and divergence outside such interval.

Comment: That is not so simple in view of `FunctionDomain[EllipticK[k^2], k, Complexes]`  resulting in `-1 + k^2 != 0`. It's unclear to me whether the integral `Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - k^2*x^2)], {x, 0, 1}]` converges for such values of `k`.

Comment: `ClearAll[k]; Integrate[1/Sqrt[(1 - x^2)*(1 - k^2*x^2)], {x, 0, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals && (k^2 > 1 || k^2 < -1)]` outputs `(-I EllipticK[1 - 1/k^2] + EllipticK[1/k^2])/Abs[k]`.

Comment: Thank you!@cvgmt@user64494

Comment: `EllipticK[k^2]` does converge for $k>1$ contrary to your statment:  "only in `-1 < k < 1` and ..."